# Dividing up Duplicate Rows Results into Two Rows DB2

Tags: sql, duplicates, db2, row

I am working with some data that outlines a person desired way of receiving messages. Some customers have two methods listed on two different rows. I would like to have only one row per ID. This would mean that if a person has two delivery methods listed, the second method should be put into the row *secondary_delivery_method*. How would I create the new row and eliminate the second row for the customers that have duplicates with different methods?

Quick Example:

| ID | First Name | Last Name | Preference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | Text |
| 1 | John | Smith | Mail |

--- Should be ---

| ID | First Name | Last Name | Primary Method | Secondary Method |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Smith | Text | Mail |

The order doesn't matter, whichever is listed first in the database can be set as primary.
Current output:
[Current Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1WJm.png)

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlXoU.png)

Comment: Can you add your simple data and expected output as text not images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: How to understand, which method is 1-st and which one is 2-nd?

Comment: Use an outer join to get what you need.

Comment: Try `group by`, `max (preference)`, `nullif (min (preference), max (preference))`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select 
  id,
  max(first_name) as first_name,
  max(last_name) as last_name,
  max(case when rn = 1 then preference end) as primary_method,
  max(case when rn = 2 then preference end) as secondary_method
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id) as rn
  from t
) x
group by id;
```

Result:

```
  ID   FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME   PRIMARY_METHOD   SECONDARY_METHOD  
 ---- ------------ ----------- ---------------- ------------------ 
  1    John         Smith       Text             Mail              
  2    Anne         Doe         Twitter          null
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZbbbYoca). I added an extra row (Anne) to show the grouping.